# Is it possible to detect unused columns in my DB using Hibernate?

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I've got a MySQL database with a hundred or more tables, which is used with Hibernate, and I've come across a couple of columns that are no longer in use. That is, they still exist in the database, but not in the model. Is it possible to detect those columns in the database that are no longer in use?

Comment: What do you mean by 'not in the model'?

Answer (score 3):

There's no schema comparison tool built into Hibernate.

I'd recommend using something like [Hibernate Tools SchemaExport](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/toolsetguide.html) to generate the DDL from your Hibernate model, and then using [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html) to get the schema of the target database. Then use the schema comparison tool of your choice to find the differences.